# How to solve $x e^x + x = 1$?

Tags: lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I have seen a mathematics-related video [here](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1eg411j7jE?share_source=copy_web), which introduce a [Lambert W function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) to the audience:
$$f(x)=xe^x\\
W(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$

Then we can use $W(x)$ to solve some transcendental equation conveniently, such $x^x=4$. But he left homework at the end of the video:

> To solve equation $x e^x + x = 1$

Well, this homework made me lose sleep for 2 days. I don't know how to solve this equation with the $W(x)$. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: I don't believe this one can be solved using $W$. Maple does not find a closed-form solution, nor does Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: As the answer says, it doesn't look like there is a solution using only $W(x)$ and the usual functions. Perhaps the video had a mistake.

Comment: Yes, I am also a user of these two software. They really can't solve this equation. That's why I came here to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W.

To show this, try to rearrange the equation to a form $f(x)e^{f(x)}=c$, $f$ a function in the complex numbers and $c$ a complex constant.

$$xe^x+x=1$$

$$xe^x=1-x$$

$$\frac{x}{1-x}e^x=1$$

We see: the exponent is $x$, a polynomial in $x$, and the factor is not a polynomial in $x$. There is no chance to rearrange the equation by only elementary operations to a form where the factor is equal to the exponent. Therefore your equation is not in a form that can be solved by Lambert W.

But the equation can be solved by generalized Lambert W:

$$x=W(^0_1;-1)=-W(^{-1}_0;-1)$$

$-$ see the references below.
$\ $

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

[[Stoutemyer 2022] Stoutemyer, D. R.: Inverse spherical Bessel functions generalize Lambert W and solve similar equations containing trigonometric or hyperbolic subexpressions or their inverses. 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.00707)

Comment: This just shows _one attempt_ fails. There are many potential results of the form $f(x)e^{f(x)}=c$.

Comment: @J.G. I supplemented my answer:  "to rearrange the equation by only elementary operations".

Answer (score 2):

*May be*, the goal of the exercise is to show that we have an immediate upper bound of the solution
$$f(x)=xe^x+x-1 > xe^x-1 \implies x< W(1)=\Omega$$

Making a series expansion
$$f(x)=\left(e^{\Omega } \Omega +\Omega -1\right)+\left(e^{\Omega } (\Omega +1)+1\right)
   (x-\Omega )+\frac{1}{2} e^{\Omega } (\Omega +2) (x-\Omega )^2+O\left((x-\Omega )^3\right)$$ and a series reversion gives as an *estimate*
$$x=\Omega+\frac{1-\left(e^{\Omega }+1\right) \Omega }{1+e^{\Omega } (\Omega +1)}-\frac{e^{\Omega } (\Omega +2) \left(e^{\Omega } \Omega +\Omega -1\right)^2}{2
   \left(1+e^{\Omega } (\Omega +1)\right)^3}=0.4028\cdots$$ while the solution is $0.4011\cdots$.